# Refreshing the Cursor from SQLiteCursorLoader

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sqliteopenhelper

My project uses the [SQLiteCursorLoader library from commonsguy](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) to load data from a database into a ListView. Among that data is a simple boolean (as so far as SQLite supports booleans... that is, a number that only ever is 0 or 1) that tells the state of a checkbox. If I change the state of a checkbox in a list and then scroll the item off the list, the list item returns to the state it has when the cursor was passed in, despite the fact that the underlying database has changed. If I change the state of a bunch of checkboxes and then activate the list's `MultiChoiceMode`, all the items displayed will revert back to the state they were in when the cursor was originally passed in, despite the fact that the underlying database has changed.

Is there a way to refresh the cursor? `Cursor.requery()` is deprecated, and I don't want to have to create a new `Cursor` each time a checkbox is checked, which happens a lot. I'm also unsure of how calling `restartLoader()` several times would work, performance-wise, especially since I use `onLoadFinish()` to perform some animations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to refresh the cursor?

Call `restartLoader()` to have it reload the data.

> I don't want to have to create a new Cursor each time a checkbox is checked, which happens a lot

Used properly, a `ListView` maintains the checked state for you. You would do this via `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` and row `Views` that implement `Checkable`. The objective is to not modify the database until the user has indicated they are done messing with the checklist by one means or another (e.g., "Save" action bar item).

> I'm also unsure of how calling restartLoader() several times would work, performance-wise, especially since I use onLoadFinish() to perform some animations.

Don't call it several times. Ideally, call it zero times, by not updating the database until the user is done, at which point you are probably transitioning to some other portion of your UI. Or, call it just once per requested database I/O (e.g., at the point of clicking "Save"). Or, switch from using a `CursorAdapter` to something else, such as an `ArrayAdapter` on a set of POJOs you populate from the `Cursor`, so that the in-memory representation is modifiable in addition to being separately persistable.

Comment: While I'l admit this is nice advice in general, it's advice that doesn't help me in my particular circumstance. My application is meant to be a bank ledger, and it uses a relational database to keep track of all the important data, including if the user checked off an item to mark the transaction as posted. The list view has the attribute `android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"` so the user can activate an `ActionMode` to delete multiple items at once from the database. You can view the source here if you wish: https://bitbucket.org/MowDownJoe/vault-foss

Comment: @MowDownJoe: "that doesn't help me in my particular circumstance" -- then you will need to change your circumstance. You either need to requery the Cursor or stop using CursorAdapter, whether you like it or not.